# How to remove link when used to create PDF in laravel dompdf?

Tags: dompdf, laravel-5.4

I just make a simple html page and write content to it. I created a link when I click on that link the content of the page will converted into PDF file, I have implemented this using laravel dompdf -> https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf . Now, My problem is that all things doing good, but the PDF that is generated after click will shows that link in the PDF file. How to remove that button from PDF file.
My code :

My controller : ItemController.php

```
class ItemController extends Controller
    {
    public function pdfview(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->has('download')){
            $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdfview');
            return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
            //return $pdf->stream();
        }

        return view('pdfview');
    }
}
```

My route: web.php

```
Route::get('/pdfview',array('as'=>'pdfview','uses'=>'ItemController@pdfview'));
```

My view : pdfview.blade.php

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="rows"><br/>  
   <a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf']) }}"> Click to PDF </a> 
      <h2 align="Center"> What is PDF ? </h2><br/><br/>
      <h4> Portable Document Format (PDF) is a file format used to present and exchange documents reliably, independent of software, hardware, or operating system.</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Help me, If you understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a stylesheet that includes CSS to style your link text with `display: none;`? You'll want to use an appropriate media target, "dompdf" works for dompdf-only styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a variable to the view, i.e:

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdfview', array('pdf' => true));
...
return view('pdfview', array('pdf' => false));
```

and check the variable in the template:

```
@if(! $pdf )
   <a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf']) }}"> Click to PDF </a> 
@endif
```

Comment: have you changed both lines of code in the controller?

Comment: if you change also the last line in the controller  `return view('pdfview', array('pdf' => false));` $pdf in the view should not be undefined. I tried your code with my corrections and it works, is it someting missing?

Comment: please try to sobstitute 'pdf' => false to 'pdf' => 0 and 'pdf' => true to 'pdf' => 1 and modify the check to @if( $pdf == 0 )